# Adding trace in figure if column exists

Tags: python

I have different CSV files with different amount of columns. I want to plot them with plotly.
Despite the values in every single column, there might be a different in the amount of the columns.
One CSV has 10 columns, the next one has 15 and the next one 16.
The first 10 columns have in every CSV the same name.

However, I do not want to adapt every time the code for the single CSVs. How can I just make plotly to plot only the existing columns?

I am using pandas.
This is an example of plotting the first column of the first CSV. I have this for every column I want to plot against the time column.

```
folder_path = 'U:/Users/Admin/Temp/Aux/'
filename3 = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path1) if f.endswith("TranslationIssues.csv")][0]

df4 = pd.read_csv(folder_path+filename3)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df4['Time'], y=df4['Number of errors'], mode='markers', name='Number of errors'))
```

There must be a way to plot only the columns if they are available.

Comment: So, you want to basically plot all columns. Could you share the code you have to import your csv files? Are you using pandas or opening them as text files?

Comment: you need to look at a tutorial on how to import csv files. I'd recommend using pandas. Then check how you can get the data inside the dataframe as a matrix, and just plot the matrix (you might need to transpose it). Don;t put code as a comment. Edit your quetsion and post the code properly formatted there

Comment: Can you share the link to this tutorial, please?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html